# After Fixing Bad .htaccess File, Site Still Does Not Load

Tags: .htaccess, browser

I added some bad code to my .htaccess file, and then my site would not even load. So I went back to a previous version that was working, but the site will still not load, I don't know if this is something to do with caching ( I emptied it by the way ) but I would like to be able to test my site again. But current browser will not go to that site. Tried the site on different computer and it is now working.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
rewriteengine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ blog.php?article=$1 [QSA,L]
```

is the current .htaccess.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
rewriteengine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]

## remove ugly part of url for blog.php
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ blog.php?article=$1 [QSA,L]
```

this is the one that broke it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try uploading an empty htaccess file. The site should be work properly. Then keep adding your lines 1 by 1 until you find out which of them is causing the problem.
 you might also want to check if you accidentally uploaded your htaccess file in another folder.

Comment: Thanks completely emptying the .htaccess file fixed it.